# args getting mapped to kwargs in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, args, keyword-argument

So I was doing something yesterday and saw that this sort of thing is possible.

```
In [3]: class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data=False):
        print data
   ...:

In [4]: foo = Foo(True)
True
```

So as you can see an arg is getting mapped to an kwarg, I would like to know why this work, and how?

Kudos to those of you who can give me a relevant example.

Comment: `data` is not kwarg! It has default value.

Comment: @scriptmonster really? I believe data is a kwarg. myusuf3, where do you see that an arg is being mapped to a kwarg? I only see one kwarg (data) and no args. Am I completely missing something here?

Comment: @scriptmonster where do `kwargs` start and default values end.

Comment: @myusuf3 First of all a method could have non-default valued arguments , and then default valued argumens take place. With *args or **kwargs is the default valued arguments end. *args and **kwargs are both optional but when you use both of them you need to use them in the right order. *args could not be after **kwargs. If you do not specify double star notation there is no kwargs!

Comment: @kobejohn, I believe you are a bit confused. Data is default-valued argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, data=False):
```

Here `data` is not a `kwarg` but a parameter with a default value. If you had called `Foo` like this

```
Foo(data = True, data1 = False)
```

Here `data1` would be considered as `kwarg` and value assigned to `data` would be passed as the value to the `data` parameter. The keyword arguments can be captured like this

```
def __init__(self, data=False, **kwarg):
    print data, kwarg
```

**Case 1**

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data=False):
        print data, kwarg

Foo(True, False)
```

This will throw an error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The `__init__` expects one positional parameter or a named parameter, but you are passing two positional parameters. Thats why its throwing this error. Instead of this, if you invoked it like this

```
Foo(True, data = False)
```

It will still throw this error

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'
```

because you are passing two values for the same parameter.

**Case 2**

If you want to properly handle all the positional parameters and keyword arguments, you can use this

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs, args

Foo(True, data = False)
```

This will print,

```
{'data': False} (True,)
```

So, all the unnamed variables go to `args` parameter and all the named parameters go to `kwargs`.

**Case 3**

Even after this generalization, you might want to handle a case like this. For a particular parameter, if the user doesnt pass an explicit value you may want to use a default value. So, you can use the default parameter here

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data = False, *args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs, args, data

Foo()
Foo(data = True)
Foo(data = True, data1 = "Welcome")
Foo(True, 1, data1 = "Welcome")
# Foo(True, data1 = "Welcome", 1) # This will throw an error
```

**Output**

```
{} () False
{} () True
{'data1': 'Welcome'} () True
{'data1': 'Welcome'} (1,) True
```

In this example,

1. We don't pass a value to `data`, so default value (`False`) is assumed
2. We explicitly pass a value to `data`, so that value is taken
3. We explicitly pass a value to `data` and another keyword argument.
4. We explicitly pass a value to `data`, positional parameter and a keyword argument.
5. This will throw an error because **no positional parameter should occur after a keyword argument. Order is very important**

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a specific vocabulary split between named parameters and kwargs? I guess I have mentally made kwargs encompass all named parameters but perhaps I'm misusing the term.

Comment: `kwarg` is simply a common variable name used for accepting keyword arguments, you can use any name instead.

Comment: **nevermind. I don't want to derail this Q/A    (I'm actually asking about the reverse. Is it considered poor form to call all named parameters kwargs? I.e. not in code but when commenting or speaking about them.)

Comment: so wait are you saying that first one is a parameter with a default value but everything after that would be kwargs so if I were to do `Foo(False, True)` as in your second example it would not work?

Comment: @myusuf3 If you say `Foo(True, False)`, your code actually accepts only one positional parameter, but you are passing two parameters. So, it will throw an error.

Comment: @thefourtheye that is super weird.

Comment: @thefourtheye For completeness, it might be helpful to explain how `args` and `kwargs` are different and how both differ from positional arguments, and then also differ from positional arguments with default values.  I the OP is hung up on how these differ, and currently they are only being shown the difference between two of these.

Comment: @SethMMorton Please check now, added few more examples.

Comment: @myusuf3 Please check the answer now, I have added few more examples and explanations.

Comment: Good!  What if there was one more example with two positional parameters, one with a default argument and one without?